# Auto start and join google video hangout in chrome browser from ubuntu terminal

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts, ubuntu-14.10

I have been looking all over for this and I feel like this should be very straight forward.

I am setting up a conference room computer and I want to automate starting AND joining a google video hangout in google chrome from a script that I run in the terminal.  Very specific to start and join from terminal because I would like to do other scripting around starting, stopping, timing, etc.

```
google-chrome --start-fullscreen --app=https://hangouts.google.com/hangouts/_/company_name/room_name
```

This will open a new google-chrome web browser and get me all the way to the goal line, however I need to hit the 'Join' button to get into it.  I was wondering how I can do something similar to what I have but automatically 'Join' the hangout?

Comment: Does anyone know if this is even possible?  I have found a few things that looked like they would work but nothing panned out...

Comment: I am looking for exact same functionality. Mb something like GreaseMonkey like script can help.

Comment: Found a solution using scripts: http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/161893

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same issue while automating google hangouts.. You can below work around for ubuntu.

You can use xdotool utility to send keyboard/ mouse events. As you launch hangout conference call using CLI, focus already on join button. Just use below command just after launching hangouts. 
**xdotool key KP_Enter**

Example:
google-chrome --start-fullscreen --app=https://hangouts.google.com/hangouts/_/company_name/room_name;
sleep 10;
xdotool key KP_Enter;

Answer (score 0):

I was trying for the same thing but on OSX. I found that if you press the **return** key twice, it will join. I was unable to execute javascript to click on the button so I resorted to that.

I would think the answer be a script that does that first portion you mentioned adding on 2 return key presses on the active window which should be Google Chrome.